# Why did my mod_proxy flag stop working in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewritemap

I've created a RewriteMap to handle a large number of domain proxies. My rewrite conditions looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAPTO:${rewritemap:%1}]
  RewriteCond %{ENV:MAPTO} !=""
  RewriteRule ^.*$ http://exampledomain.com/%{ENV:MAPTO}/$0/ [P,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Basically, my RewriteMap will look at the domain coming in, match it to an entry in a database, and return something like "user/userid".

This would, for example, display the incoming domain in the address bar, but display the content returned at http://exampledomain.com/user/userid/

Now, for some reason, I'm getting a 301 redirect to http://exampledomain.com/user/userid/ — no proxy. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, <s>it's because I turned on output buffering</s>. From the Apache doc:

> [Be sure to turn off buffering in your program.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg)

<s>Turned it off and now it's working.</s>

## Update

This, apparently, did not solve the problem. Not sure why it seemed to work and now isn't. If anyone else has any suggestions, I'll take them.

## Update 2

Okay, this time I removed the trailing slash and it seems to work:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://exampledomain.com/%{ENV:MAPTO}/$0 [P,NC]
```

I'm guessing if the incoming domain had no directory or file names it was closing with a double trailing slash and this was causing the page to redirect.